# Adding battery percentage to my widget

Tags: java, android, xml, widget, battery

I am building a widget for homescreen,
now I added time to it, I want to add battery percentage to it how canI do it?

public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
}

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, HelloWidget.class);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, format.format(new Date()));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}

}
```

}

this is my main java file, any way to add the percentage?

i tried this

```
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

but i cant but it correctly, please help

Comment: Does anything display in batteryTxt?  Looks like you're on the right track. Have you tried [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/05/android-battery-percentage-example.html#.UwOYEvgu3v4) tutorial? Very similar to what you have done with some extra steps in the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: it gives me many errors

Comment: Add them to your question, they will be useful in solving your problem.